# Run next request with new iteration data from json by using setNextRequest in postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a case where i have a folder in a collection which has to run for a specific set of iterations before going to the next folder.

There is no direct feature in postman yet which allows you to set different iterations at each folder level and still run the collection as whole.

I want to run a specific request in a folder with all the testdata i provide in a json and then move to the next request as per the collection folders.

I tried achieving the same using `setNextRequest` in the same request which has to be run multiple times but with different data.

However, it runs the same data again for the second time as well and through the runner it goes to iteration 2 which was set to 2 at collection level as well.

How can I achieve my usecase.

Comment: so for each folder you need to iterate over separated data list(with different structure), right? is there a reason why running each folder separately over different CSV files cannot be done?

Comment: As per my understanding, if i want to run each folder separately using its own test data, then i cannot set it at a collection level where i can get consolidated reports. In my case, there are multiple folders in a collection and a few folders are such that, a specific request has to run for the whole test data set before going to the next request in the same folder.